# How to avoid "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" using Laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

considering the following code, using Postgres+Laravel 5.2:

```
$post = Post::firstOrNew(['title'=> 'title test']);
$post->body = 'test body';
$post->save();
```

whenever multiple processes works on the same data raw I get
`Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint..`

I've tried to use transactions as suggested here
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-properly-use-the-lockforupdate-method 
but then I got `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()`

for instance: `Post::firstOrNew([...])->lockForUpdate()`

How can I possibly solve this problem

Comment: Doesn't `firstOrNew()` takes two paramenters? What are you offering to query if it `exists` or is `new`?

Comment: I encountered this problem while generating fake models, each of which themselves generated a fake related model. The solution was to generate the related model once, and assign it to each during their creation.

Answer (score -1):

just wrap it up in a try catch block and catch QueryException If you just want to get ridd of it.